# Windows 7 Can't Get Past Format

Tags: windows-7, installation, power-management

Just assembled a new machine:

MSI 880GM-E41 motherboard
500GB Samsung hard drive
AMD Athlon II X4 640 processor
4GB RAM
Windows 7 64 Bit
LITE-ON Black 4X Blu-ray reader

I boot up, start the install. When it gets to the screen to select what partition, the motherboard loses power. It doesnt make sense, I can leave it in the bios settings for a very long time and it doesnt lose power. When it does lose power, the monitor shuts down and the mouse loses power, but the power light stays on. I cannot tell if it is a hardware or software problem.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like either the motherboard or PSU. I'd first try a different PSU and see if that solves the problem.  If not, then I'd peg the motherboard.

Comment: Stupid question: is the switch on the back of the PSU set to the right voltage? We had a problem with PSUs that came from the suppliers set to 220V and we're on 110V here. Took us a day to figure it out, but it was a simple issue.

Comment: @Soren, attempt installing with only one stick of RAM in the first ram slot. Additionally what brand and model of memory do you have?

Comment: @Tyler the memory is G.SKILL Ripjaws Series 4GB (2 x 2GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1333 (PC3 10666) Desktop Memory Model F3-10666CL9D-4GBRL

Comment: The power supply is set at 115V.

Comment: I took the hard drive to work today and fromatted it. It didnt make any difference. I have tried switching the memory around, no difference. The Windows 7 install get to "expanding files" then no power to video or mouse. But, the fans are still running.

Comment: Does anyone know if any of my hardware just isnt compatible with windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. So, I disabled the floppy drive and something called AMD Cool and Quiet in the BIOS and got Windows 7 64 bit installed in about 15 minutes.

Comment: You should accept this answer. Cool and Quiet lowers the power consumption of your processor by underclocking it, allowing it to run cooler and have the fan be slower. It's possible with the lower fan speed it was over heating, or with being underclocked it was unstable. If you have further stability issues, I would check your memory voltages and timings in the BIOS and be sure they match the manufacturer recommended settings.

Comment: It could be a known issue. The voltage could be incorrect in BIOS and can lead to overheat. Disabling CnQ will lead to the use of different BIOS settings and a more stable system. But, you may still have some issues, just maybe slower allowing an install. See: http://forums.amd.com/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=11&threadid=98342&enterthread=y

Comment: Just a quick update.... After getting Windows installed, I did re-enable the Cool and Quiet feature in the bios and have not had any issues.

Answer (score 0):

What power supply are you using? I'd suspect that one first.

Try different parts one-by-one, if you have any extras, starting with the HD, the RAM, the PSU (to a beefier one).

Comment: Rosewill 500W (Model:DR-8500BTX) http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811147081

Comment: PSU should probably be enough. What kind of video card, or onboard?

Comment: Onboard video. I havent added anything extra.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to boot it with a live CD such as PartedMagic? Does it work?

Notice:

*Considering problem with HDD*

Comment: No, I havent tried that. But, I did start an install of Windows XP and it got past the formatting part.

Comment: I'm going to take the hard drive to work with me today, plug it into a SATA/USB connector and format it from a Windows 7 machine then see what happens tonight.